# ZingChart context menu styles issue

Tags: zingchart

I'm trying to add some css styles to ZingChart context menu, but default inline styles override them. Is it possible to clear all styles for context menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to clear the styles. You can adjust them with our [JSON syntax](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/gui/context-menu/). If you need to use CSS. Just use the most popular stackoverflow answer... !important

```
.zc-menu.zc-style {
  background:red !important;
}
```

Demo of adjusting context menu styles

```js
var myTheme = {
  palette:{
    line:[
        ['#FBFCFE', '#00BAF2', '#00BAF2', '#00a7d9'], /* light blue */
        ['#FBFCFE', '#E80C60', '#E80C60', '#d00a56'], /* light pink */
        ['#FBFCFE', '#9B26AF', '#9B26AF', '#8b229d'], /* light purple */
        ['#FBFCFE', '#E2D51A', '#E2D51A', '#E2D51A'], /* med yellow */
        ['#FBFCFE', '#FB301E', '#FB301E', '#e12b1b'], /* med red */
        ['#FBFCFE', '#00AE4D', '#00AE4D', '#00AE4D'], /* med green */
    ]
  },
  graph:{
    backgroundColor:'#FBFCFE',
    title: {
      fontFamily: 'Lato',
      fontSize: 14,
      // border: "1px solid black",
      padding: "15",
      fontColor : "#1E5D9E",
      adjustLayout:true
    },
    subtitle: {
      fontFamily: 'Lato',
      fontSize: 12,
      fontColor: "#777",
      padding: "5"
    },
    plot: {
      backgroundColor:'#FBFCFE',
      marker: {
        size: 4
      }
    },
   tooltip : {
        visible:true,
        text: "%kl<br><span style='color:%color'>%t: </span>%v<br>",
        backgroundColor : "white",
        borderColor : "#e3e3e3",
        borderRadius : "5px",
        bold : true,
        fontSize : "12px",
        fontColor : "#2f2f2f",
        textAlign : 'left',
        padding : '15px',
        shadow : true,
        shadowAlpha : 0.2,
        shadowBlur : 5,
        shadowDistance : 4,
        shadowColor : "#a1a1a1"
    },
    plotarea: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderRadius: "0 0 0 10",
      borderRight: "0px",
      borderTop: "0px",
      margin:"dynamic",
      borderLeft:'1px solid #1E5D9E',
      borderBottom:'1px solid #1E5D9E',
    },
   scaleX: {
      zooming:true,
      offsetY: -20,
      lineWidth: 0,
      padding: 20,
      margin: 20,
      label:{
        text:"Scale-X"
      },
      item: {
        padding: 5,
        fontColor : "#1E5D9E",
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        rules: [
          {
            rule: "%i == 0",
            visible: false
          }
        ]
      },
      tick: {
        lineColor: '#D1D3D4',
        rules: [
          {
            rule: "%i == 0",
            visible: false
          }
        ]
      },
      guide: {
        visible: true,
        lineColor : '#D7D8D9',
        lineStyle: 'dotted',
        lineGapSize: '4px',
        rules: [
          {
            rule: "%i == 0",
            visible: false
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    scaleY: {
      zooming:true,
      lineWidth: 0,
      label:{
        text:"Scale-Y"
      },
      item: {
        padding: "0 10 0 0",
        fontColor : "#1E5D9E",
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        rules: [
          {
            rule: "%i == 0",
            offsetX:10,
            offsetY:10,
            backgroundColor:'none'
          }
        ]
      },
      tick: {
        lineColor: '#D1D3D4',
        rules: [
          {
            rule: "%i == 0",
            visible:false
          }
        ]
      },
      guide: {
        visible: true,
        lineColor : '#D7D8D9',
        lineStyle: 'dotted',
        lineGapSize: '4px',
        rules: [
          {
            rule: "%i == 0",
            visible: false
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    scrollX:{
      bar:{
        backgroundColor:'none',
       borderLeft:'none',
        borderTop:'none',
        borderBottom:'none'
      },
      handle:{
        backgroundColor:'#1E5D9E',
        height:5
      }
    },
    scrollY:{
      borderWidth:0,
      bar:{
        backgroundColor:'none',
        width:14,
        borderLeft:'none',
        borderTop:'none',
        borderBottom:'none'
      },
      handle:{
        borderWidth:0,
        backgroundColor:'#1E5D9E',
        width:5
      }
    },
    zoom:{
      backgroundColor:'#1E5D9E',
      alpha:.33,
      borderColor:'#000',
      borderWidth:1
    },
    preview:{
      borderColor:'#1E5D9E',
      borderWidth:1,
      adjustLayout:true,
      handle:{
        backgroundColor:'#1E5D9E',
        borderColor:'#1E5D9E'
      },
      mask:{
        backgroundColor:'#FFF',
        alpha:.95,
      }
    }
  }
};
 
var myConfig = {
  type: "line",
  title: {
    text: "Average requests Per Minute",
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: "06/10/16 - 06/23/16",
  },
  plotarea: {
    marginTop:10,
    marginBottom:80
  },
 scaleX: {
    zooming:true,
    labels:['6/10','6/11','6/12','6/13','6/14','6/15','6/16','6/17','6/18','6/19','6/20','6/21','6/22','6/23']
  },
  scaleY: {
    zooming:true,
  },
  preview:{},
  scrollX:{},
  scrollY:{},
 series : [
  {
    text: "Internal",
   values : [6,6,3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 2.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5],
  },
  {
    text: "External",
   values : [4.5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 3, 3, 2],
  },
  {
    text: "Outbound",
   values : [2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
  }
 ]
};
 
zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
  data: {
    gui:{
      contextMenu:{
        button:{
          visible: true,
          lineColor: "#2D66A4",
          backgroundColor: "#2D66A4"
        },
        gear: {
          alpha: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#2D66A4"
        },
        position: "right",
        backgroundColor:"#306EAA", /*sets background for entire contextMenu*/
        docked: true, 
        item:{
          backgroundColor:"#306EAA",
          borderColor:"#306EAA",
          borderWidth: 0,
          fontFamily: "Lato",
          color:"#fff"
        }
      }
    },
    graphset:[myConfig]
  },
 height: 390, 
 width: '100%',
 defaults: myTheme
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script></head>
 <body>
   <section>
    <div id='myChart'></div>
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was hoping this is not the only option. But thanks.